# React import: Navigate one folder up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have the following project structure:

- src

  - FolderA

    - File3.js
  - FolderB

    - File2.js
  - File1.js

---

Within File2.js i want to import a function from File3.js. I have tried

```
import MyFunction from '/../FolderA/File3.js';
```

=> im **outside of /src** which isnt supported

```
import MyFunction from './FolderA/File3.js';
```

=> Module not found: Can't resolve './FolderA/File3.js' in **'C:\PATH_TO_SRC\src\FolderB'**

**EDIT**

i have also tried

```
import MyFunction from '../FolderA/File3.js';
```

and

```
import MyFunction from './../FolderA/File3.js';
```

=> Module not found: Can't resolve '../FolderA/File3.js' in 'C:\PATH_TO_SRC\src\FolderB'

---

Do i miss something here? I have tried multiple variations and all didnt work.

If import something within File1.js with

```
import MyOtherFunction from './FolderA/File2.js';
```

it works fine...

Comment: `import MyFunction from '../FolderA/File3.js';`

Comment: or `./../FolderA/File3.js` but I obviously would go for the easier one (kuby's one)

Comment: I have tried it => Module not found: Can't resolve '../FolderA/File3.js' in 'C:\PATH_TO_SOURCE\src\FolderB'   :/

Comment: @AliceTheCat Could you include a screen shot of your folder structure? You might have a folder in a folder, or something similar.

Comment: @Tholle Thanks. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the first `/` in `import MyFunction from '/../FolderA/File3.js';` and it will work as expected.

```
import MyFunction from '../FolderA/File3.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

'/../FolderA/File3.js'; should be '../FolderA/File3.js';
With dots on begin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tholle. I havent noticed that there was an addtional folder.

```
import MyFunction from '../FolderA/OtherFolder/File3.js';
```

worked like charm! Sorry for this question /*facepalm/ and thanks for your time! :)